# Swift Dictionary<String , Array> add new key/value

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, dictionary, swift2

I have a Dictionary of key string and value Array :

```
var dicToAdd = [String : [ComplexObject]]()

class ComplexObject {
   let id : Int
   let tracer : String
}
```

When I have an array of ComplexObject variable and try to add it to the dictionary , it doesn't give any error but the key/value is not added :

```
var someComplexObjectArray = [ComplexObject]()

//someComplexObjectArray is filled with over 50+ elements
...   

dicToAdd["First"] = someComplexObjectArray
```

results in (Debug window)

```
dicToAdd = ([String : [ComplexObject]]) 0 key/value pairs
```

Any suggestions as XCode doesn't throw any errors but I end up with an empty dictionary ?

Comment: What is the value of somComplexObjectArray

Comment: someComplexObjectArray is filled with over 50 elements the code is too long where it is being filled so I didn't post the whole code of filling the array

Comment: What is giving you the console output that you are reporting?

Comment: Also, variables begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Is someComplexObjectArray an optional? Then do `dicToAdd["First"] = someComplexObjectArray`

Comment: The code as written works fine for me, except the class won't compile because it needs an `init`. Once I added an init it worked fine.

Comment: @BurakGazi what is giving you this output? Are you in a playground? Try adding `dictToAdd` to the last line of the playground.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `someComplexObjectArray` is `nil` or something else you do not expect. Check for the following:

- The variable you are modifying is not of the type you expect.
- The variable you are assigning is not what you expect.
- After reading the value, it is not displayed correctly. (E.g., see what dicToAdd["First"]` contains instead of relying on the count.)
- After setting the value you change it again, or remove the key, or reinitialize the variable before reading it.

Comment: No, it is set and has over 50 values inside

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: In Swift you can't set an array to nil